# how to get min&Max values from vector<Mat> collection of 2D images opencv c++

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to get the `min` & `max` values from a collection of gray images. 
I need to convert this code from `matlab` to `c++` code using `opencv`.

The code is:

```
qGrey(1) = min(min(reff(:))); qGrey(2) = max(max(reff(:)));
```

`reff` is `3 D {25,171,121}` , `25` is number of images. I tried `minMaxLoc` & `minMaxIdx` but it only worked in one image.

Comment: No opencv way. Loop through all images one by one and call `cv::minMaxLoc` on each. Maybe you can use `std::max_element` with custom Compare lambda. I think you get the point.

Comment: @michelson ,thanks for your reply , i'm beginner at this how can i use it with vector<Mat> to get max or min i got syntax error  when i use std::max_element(vecName)

Answer (score 0):

To get `cv::Mat` containing max element you can use:

```
auto it = std::max_element(v.begin(), v.end(), [](cv::Mat a, cv::Mat b) -> bool {
    double max_a, max_b;
    cv::minMaxLoc(a, nullptr, &max_a);
    cv::minMaxLoc(b, nullptr, &max_b);
    return max_a < max_b;
});  
cv::Mat max_mat = *it; //max_element returns iterator pointing to max element
```

To get max value from all the `cv::Mat`s in `std::vector` you can use:

```
double all_max = 0., all_min = 0.;
cv::minMaxLoc(vec[0], &all_min, &all_max);
for(int i=1; i<vec.size(); i++) {
    double tmp_min = 0., tmp_max = 0.;
    cv::minMaxLoc(vec[i], &tmp_min , &tmp_max);
    if(tmp_max > all_max) all_max = tmp_max;
    if(tmp_min < all_min) all_min = tmp_min;
}
```